# Query Geode data by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, geode

Because Geode removed the Spark connector for years, 
I would like to know how a Spark application could access it ?

I tried to search it before, I found there is a github repository :
[Spark Geode Connector](https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/geode-spark-connector)
, except this kind of 3rd plugin, are there some **other ideas**?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Geode does not support Spark anymore. That said, if there is enough community interest, this position could be reevaluated.

As you stated, the repository mentioned is 3rd party maintained.